# How to generate textarea dynamically when checkbox is checked in angular2

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am new to Angular2, trying to generate textarea dynamically when checkbox is checked and delete textarea when checkbox is unchecked in angular2., Is there any better solution? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `ngModel` and then store it as a variable:

```
<input type="checkbox" #isVisible="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="isTextareaVisible">
```

Then use an `*ngIf` to toggle it:

```
<textarea *ngIf="isVisible"></textarea>
```

Sidenote: If this is inside a form tag, don't forget to add a `name="isTextareaVisible"` attribute to the `input`, or angular will complain.

Comment: Thanks Chrillewoodz,  but i need this in click event like (change)="textarea($event)" ,how javascript uses var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water"); node.appendChild(textnode); document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" #mycheckbox />
<textarea *ngIf="mycheckbox.value"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr victor, but i need this in click event like (change)="textarea($event)" ,how javascript uses  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

Comment: it's not an angular way, but what's your problem?